# Output of call function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var a = "asd";
toString.call(a); //prints [object String]
```

Why does this not the same as `a.toString();`? The value of `this` within the toString function would be a in both cases right? I expected it output "asd" (same as `a.toString()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you use is the `window.toString`, but it should be:

```
String.prototype.toString.call(a)  // then it should be same
```

Comment: How is window.toString() different from String.prototype.toString()? Is there any documentation explaining the behavior of window.toString()?

Comment: They are just different implementations.

Comment: @xdazz - I believe `toString` in `window` has different native code than `toString` in `String` just like `forEach` in `Array` and `Node List`

Answer (score 0):

They are different methods (although they have the same name). In addition to [@xdazz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21178448/283863), to prove that `toString` behaves differently in other types:

```
[].toString.call("abc");  //Array
```

This will also not return `"abc"`.

---

```
document.querySelectorAll("*").toString.call("abc")  //Node List
```

Not `"abc"`.

---

```
(2).prototype.toString.call("abc")  //Number
```

Error, and also `toString` in Number also can have a radix argument.

---

Conclusion: They are all different. Since `window` is some kind of weird `Object`, it doesn't share the same `toString` as `String`'s.